# Sitecore HTML Editor throwing 404 error: Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Dialogs.EditHtml.aspx misisng

Tags: html, sitecore, editor, content-editor

The Edit HTML dialog in my Sitecore site was working previously but now when I click the Edit HTML button I get a 404 error, for this requested URL:  /sitecore/shell/~/xaml/sitecore_xaml.ashx/sitecore/shell/~/xaml/Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Dialogs.EditHtml.aspx

Comment: We're getting the same issue with a different file:
/sitecore/shell/~/xaml/sitecore_xaml.ashx/sitecore/shell/~/xaml/Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Editors.Folder.aspx

Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

The URL to should be pointing to:

/sitecore/shell/~/xaml/Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.Dialogs.EditHtml.aspx

What version are you using?  I'm not sure for other versions but this one is for SC 8.2 update 4.